# getElementsByClassName recursion

Tags: javascript, function, dom, recursion, polyfills

I have been trying to implement a getElementsByClassName function that behaves exactly like the DOM method. Through much research I have come up with the following but it seems that what is returned does not match what the standard method will return. The last `console.log` statement appears to print what I am looking for but somehow what is returned differs. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var results= [];
  var bod = document.body;
    var iterateBod = function(bod){

    if(bod.classList && bod.classList.contains(className)){
        results.push(bod); 
        console.log(results)
    }else{
        for(var i = 0; i < bod.childNodes.length; i++){
            iterateBod(bod.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    };

iterateBod(bod);
console.log(results);
return results;
};
```

Comment: why do you stop iterating if the object has a matching class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the condition inside recursion

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
var results= [];
var bod = document.body;
  var iterateBod = function(bod){
    if(bod.classList && bod.classList.contains(className))
     {
     results.push(bod); 
     console.log(results);
     if(bod.childNodes)
     {
         for(var i = 0; i < bod.childNodes.length; i++)
         {
             iterateBod(bod.childNodes[i]);
         }
     }
   }
 };

iterateBod(bod);
console.log(results);
return results;
};
```

Comment: This did the trick but I am still murky of my understanding of why this worked. Could you provide and explanation of what this does compared to my original attempt? I want to make sure I have a strong grasp on the concept.

Comment: The default function doesn't stop the recursion inside DOM after the class found. Already had a comment by Sebas. I just modify your code.